# Adding event listener on all $.goMap markers on the map

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, google-maps-markers

I have been trying to add a click listener to every single marker on the map created with the jQuery extension $.goMap.

This is how I load all the markers into the map:

```
$.getJSON('get_markers.php', function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(pair) {
        id = data[pair]['id'];
        $.goMap.createMarker({
            latitude: data[pair]['lat'],
            longitude: data[pair]['lng'],
            draggable: false,
            html: {
                ajax: 'marker_description.php?q=' + id,
                content: 'loading...'
            }
        });
    });
});
```

I looked into the HTML to see if I could figure out the id or class of the markers, to then use jQuery to attach a click listener to all of them, but couldn't find them in my html markup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by adding a listener to each marker in the for loop after creating them. I added an id attribute to the marker in order to create the listeners.

```
$.getJSON('get_markers.php', function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(pair) {
        var id = data[pair]['id'];
        $.goMap.createMarker({
            latitude: data[pair]['lat'],
            longitude: data[pair]['lng'],
            draggable: false,
            id: id
            /*html: {
                ajax: 'marker_description.php?q=' + id,
                content: 'loading...'
            }*/
        });

        $.goMap.createListener({type:'marker', marker:id}, 'click', function() { 
                $.ajax({
                  url: "show_post.php?q="+id,
                  success: function(html){
                    $("#results").html(html);
                  }
                });
            });

    });
});
```

Would this hurt performance though? Not sure.

Answer (score -1):

```
$.goMap.createListener({type:'marker', marker:'testMarker'}, 'click', function() { 
        console.log('marker click');
    });
```